# emulator problems on MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

I have tried the following code on nox7.1.2 with no errors, and I use this method in some places like onDestroy() onCreate() and so on:

```
 private void StartMusic()
{
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splash_music);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private void StopMusic()
{
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

But when I tried that on Android emulator (pixel API27) I've been faced with force close on the emulator. Maybe the following sentence shows the cause of the problem but I can't figure it why. In addition, when I comment upward codes and all usage of these methods, App do properly with no problem on Android emulator.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/splash_music.MP3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0000

Comment: do you have that mp3 file in res/raw/ folder?

Comment: yes, and the file play on nox7.1.2, but on Android Emulator the App leaves with force close.

Comment: try these steps : 1 clean and rebuild project , 2 restart  emulator, 3 restarting the adb server by running adb kill-server and adb start-server from the command line